# How do you append new records only in query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create a append query and it seems like my syntax is wrong.
When I run the append query I don't want old records to be appended again but rather just the new records. I will include my SQL statement. This is also being run in access.

---

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( District, Location, PricePerTon )
    SELECT TestFormWithDeficiency1.District, 
        TestFormWithDeficiency1.Location, 
        TestFormWithDeficiency1.PricePerTon
    FROM TestFormWithDeficiency1
        WHERE (((TestFormWithDeficiency1.RecordCopy)=Yes))
        Where Not Exist (
            Select Location 
            Form Table1 
            Where Table1.Location=TestFormWithDeficiency1.Location);
```

Comment: You have `WHERE` twice, use `AND`. Also, it's `EXISTS` with an `s`

Comment: Im not familiar with the AND and EXISTS operators could you please edit my SQL statement and show me if you dont mind.

Comment: You've never heard of `AND`?

Comment: You also say `Select Location Form Table1` in your `EXISTS` block - `Form` should be `FROM`

Comment: Thank you Darren. and yes i have heard of and but do i need to write `AND (expression 1)` or `AND expression 1`. Ive only just started with learning SQL and Database Mngmnt.

Comment: _"it seems like my syntax is wrong"_ Why? Do you get an error? What was it, quoted in full? Or did it give you no error but do the wrong thing? What did you want it to do? What happened instead? This is a very unclear question, and besides, it demonstrates a lack of basic research about the language being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When more than one condition in your where clause exists, use `AND` instead of a second `where`

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( District, Location, PricePerTon )
SELECT TestFormWithDeficiency1.District, 
       TestFormWithDeficiency1.Location, 
       TestFormWithDeficiency1.PricePerTon
FROM TestFormWithDeficiency1
WHERE TestFormWithDeficiency1.RecordCopy=Yes
AND NOT EXISTS (Select Location -- AND instead of second WHERE
                FROM Table1  -- FROM instead of FORM
                WHERE Table1.Location=TestFormWithDeficiency1.Location);
```

Comment: That work and thank you for explaining i appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `EXISTS` join the tables so that all records in `TestFormWithDeficiency1` are returned and only the matching records in `Table1`.  You can then check which `Table1.Location` is null.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( District, Location, PricePerTon )
SELECT      TestFormWithDeficiency1.District
            , TestFormWithDeficiency1.Location
            , TestFormWithDeficiency1.PricePerTon
FROM        TestFormWithDeficiency1 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON TestFormWithDeficiency1.Location = Table1.Location
WHERE       RecordCopy=Yes AND Table1.Location IS NULL
```

**Note:** In the `WHERE` clause I haven't specified the table for `RecordCopy`.  This assumes that field doesn't exist in `Table1`.  As it only appears in one table it doesn't need to be fully qualified with the table name.

On a large table this should run a bit faster than using a subquery (or is that a correlated query?)